# How to get the latest code to be executed of console application

Tags: c#, console-application

Actually i have a window service which calls a console application every 5 seconds, for this i have created a folder in D drive and the release files of console application are copy/pasted there but whenever i make any changes in code and copy/paste the latest dlls from the bin/release folder latest code is not getting executed.

Comment: Are you updating the files of your Windows Service or those of the console application? Did you try and restart the Windows Service?

Comment: No sir, actually i wanted to know how to deploy latest code changes from console application

Comment: This seems like a very strange design. Why would you need a Windows Service to call a Console application? Just create a DLL and have the Windows Service consume code from that DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have installed (knowingly or indirectly via VS) the assemblies in the GAC (Global assembly cache). The GAC has priority over local files.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28VS.71%29.aspx) for more information.